# Data binding between custom directive and controller

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I have custom directive that communicates with external library to collect data.

This directive is attached to component's template. It does what it is supposed to do.

External library, which is integrated to directive sends data to it constantly. How do I bind the data between directive and the component where the directive is being used?

I have implemented data binding between, controller and template. Does the data binding happen the same way between directive and component?

Comment: You could use a `Output()` in the directive to emit the data to the component always, when it is changed

Comment: @Daniomi - So is the same way we do data binding between template and controller?

Comment: In general yes. You say the directive is working well and the data is updated there correctly. So any time the data is updated in the directive you `emit` the updated data with an output and call a component method to bind the data to the template with a property. Do you need more information?

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you. I wanted to make sure I am not going against angular arch by doing this approach and know if there are any alternates.

Comment: updated the answer with code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `@Output` angular decorator.

**Inside directive:**

```
@Output('ap-data-change') apDataChange: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter() 

// or any function that updates data
onChange() {
  ... 
  this.apDataChange.next(someValue);
}
```

Within the **host component** using directive:

```
<div [ap-data]="[1,2,3,4,5]" (ap-data-change)=hostField=event$></div>
```

Alternatively, this can be passed to a function like:

```
<div [ap-data]="[1,2,3,4,5]" (ap-data-change)="_messageReceiver($event)"></div>
```